# Correct way to handle crash reports on iOS

Tags: ios

Apple documentation says I may use crash report service (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH21-SW1), but many people on Internet say it is unstable and slow service, so it is better to obtain reports with something like `plcrashreporter` and process them manually.

Is it still true in 2015? Should I stay with apple service or handle crash manually? Can I simply catch any exception with `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` , log it and then rethrow?

Comment: Use the Apple service until you reach the point that it won't do what you want. It should be fine for >99% of all problems. If you run into a problem that requires real-time monitoring of your apps then perhaps something that requires more code & support is the way to go.

Comment: @RoboticCat thanks. Just to be sure I understand apple service correctly: if my app crashes on user iPhone  I will be able to get crash log in Apple Developer Portal, correct?

Comment: Yes - although not every crash as the user needs to be sending diagnostic information back to Apple. You will end up with a representative sample provided enough people have downloaded your app. If your app is very complex then I recommend writing tests in Xcode and carrying out automated testing in Xcode as well.

Comment: Thanks, I already use XCTests, but I really afraid of situation when customer reports app crash, and I can't help her. So, I'll use apple crash reports

Comment: There's no guarantee you'll be able to duplicate a crash even with crash reports. You might want to look into Activity Tracing to get the most out of the crash reports although this is not yet easily implemented using Swift.